# OpenERP - Error: No module named Image

Tags: python, odoo

I am running OpenERP 6.0.3, Windows 7, server from Apatana IDE. Server starts and runs fine. When I login using OpenERP GTK Client, I get the error in the console:

```
[2015-03-27 11:48:34,996][adamson_prod] INFO:init:module pyqr: loading objects
[2015-03-27 11:48:34,996][adamson_prod] INFO:init:module pyqr: registering objects
[2015-03-27 11:48:34,996][adamson_prod] CRITICAL:init:Couldn't load module pyqr
[2015-03-27 11:48:34,996][adamson_prod] CRITICAL:init:No module named Image
```

There is a module pyqr in my addons. I installed PIL for Python. Why I am getting these errors and what do I need to do to eliminate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to install correct PIL version which is [PIL-1.1.7.win-amd64-py2.7.exe](https://github.com/lightkeeper/lswindows-lib/blob/master/amd64/python/PIL-1.1.7.win-amd64-py2.7.exe?raw=true).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, those errors come from the pyqr module, which could be wrongly installed. You should check if it is installed correctly.

More specifically these two lines:

```
[2015-03-27 11:48:34,996][adamson_prod] CRITICAL:init:Couldn't load module pyqr
[2015-03-27 11:48:34,996][adamson_prod] CRITICAL:init:No module named Image
```

this indicates that the pyqr module could not initialize because the module named Image is missing. To fix this you should reinstall the module.

Comment: As I mentioned I have folder pyqr in my addons. How I can install a module when I cannot even login to OpenERP? Thanks.

Comment: Pyqr uses the module Image the error tells me that python cannot find this module in the PYTHONPATH. Can you reach the server in another way? so you can see if the module exists?

Comment: I have checked "addons" folder, there is no folder "Image". When I run OpenERP server in Aptana, I am getting a message in console "WARNING:init:Python Imaging not installed, you can use only .JPG pictures !", but I did install PIL for Python 2.7. I wonder if this has to do something with the error message in question.